# SQLite boolean column where only one entry can be true

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I am using Python, Peewee and SQLite.

I need to model a table of entries where at most one entry can be in an "active" state.
So there is a boolean column named `is_active`.

How can I express a constraint in Peewee that makes sure that only zero or one rows have `is_active == True`?

Also, during creation of an entry, `is_active` should not be allowed to be set, it should always be `False` initially.
The only way to set it to `True` should be through an `activate()` method on the model that first deactivates the remaining entries.
How can I "hide" this attribute during entry creation?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few approaches here:

#### 1st

Define a `CHECK` constraint for the `is_active` column and create a user-defined `FUNCTION`. The new function would go back to the database and query the table in order to validate the results from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE is_active = 1`. If is `0` then `activate`, otherwise trigger the constraint error. See [1](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#single-column-indexes-and-constraints) (`check` constraint in Peewee) and [2](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/sqlite_ext.html) (user defined functions in Peewee).

#### 2nd

Create a [DB trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) directly on the DB. You can do this by having an `init.sql` file or similar, which runs during the setup of your project. This trigger will work in a similar way to the function of the first approach, but "triggered" now with a `BEFORE INSERT` clause. This is a more preferred way than using functions, since triggers somehow act like hooks. From the peewee side this can be handled via the [signals extension](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#signal-support). You might want to look at the `pre_save` hook.

#### 3rd

Override the `save` method in your model class so before you call `super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` again you check that there is no existing row where `is_active = 1`. As an advise, I suggest you to override only the `save` function, which acts at the model level, and avoid overriding other SQL generation functions like `update` or `select`.

And finally here are my comments regarding the other items you asked about:

- For the default value just use `is_active = BooleanField(default=False)`
- For protecting the `is_active` field from being set. I might not be giving you the best advice on this one, since I haven't dealt with something like this in the past, but the only way I can think of is by making the attribute/column private on its definition, that way you can only modify it via the `activate` function, which would be within your DB Model. Alternatively I can think of using the [`peewee hybrid attributes`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#hybrid-attributes) to define a custom accessor that raises an error when it's being assigned/set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, these seem like useful approaches. I skipped the topic for now but will come back to it at a later time and accept the answer when I got it working.